# Is this process a Brownian motion? A martingale problem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $(M_t)$ be a martingale w.r.t a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$. The martingale representation theorem implies there exists a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$ such that $M_t$ is the solution of an SDE of the form

$$dM_t=\sigma(t,M_t)d B_t $$

Suppose that we found a process $(X_t)$ adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$ such that

$$dM_t=\tilde \sigma(t,M_t)d X_t $$

Does that mean that $(X_t)$ is a Brownian motion? If so, what is the theorem behind that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $M_t$ is a martingale which is not a Brownian motion with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_t)$, then you can just pick $dX_t = dM_t$ and $\tilde{\sigma} = 1$.

Comment: Makes sense. But in the case where $M_t$ and $X_t$ are distinct, would the answer be different ?

Comment: By scaling, the answer would still be no. More interestingly, if $dM_t = s(t,M_t) r(t, M_t) dB_t$ with $r, s \in L^2$, then you could always have $dX_t = r(t, M_t) dB_t$.